# Why am I not able to build Vim with Visual Studio 2015 RC command line tools?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, vim, visual-studio-2015

Yesterday, I installed [Visual Studio 2015 RC Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions). As a first test, I tried building GVim from source.

I opened a command window using `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\Visual Studio Tools\Windows Desktop Command Prompts\VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt.lnk"`, set

```
set include=%include%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include
```

so [`Make_mvc.mak`](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/Make_mvc.mak) picks up the `Win32.mak` file. Also, I set:

```
set MSVCVER=12.0
```

as the [make file](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/Make_mvc.mak) does not detect the new Visual Studio version at this point.

After this, I have:

```
Framework40Version=v4.0
FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
FrameworkDIR64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
FSHARPINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.10056.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.10056.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;
LIBPATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;
MSVCVER=12.0
Platform=X64
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\
VisualStudioVersion=14.0
VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
windir=C:\Windows
WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\
WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\
```

I am able to build a simple program:

```
C:\...\Temp> type t.c                          
#include                                                    

int main(void) {                                                     
    printf("Hello %s\n", "Stackoverflow.com");                       
    return 0;                                                        
}                                                                    

C:\...\Temp> cl t.c                            
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.22816 for x64  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.           

t.c                                                                  
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.22816.0               
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.           

/out:t.exe                                                           
t.obj                                                                

C:\...\Temp> t.exe                             
Hello Stackoverflow.com
```

However, when I issue the command to build my GVim (something which works fine with Visual Studio 2013 CE tools), the compilation goes fine, but I get the following link errors:

```
C:\...\vim\src> nmake -f Make_mvc.mak CPU=AMD64 OPTIMIZE=SPACE GETTEXT=no NETBEANS=no CSCOPE=no DIRECTX=yes GUI=yes
```

I am snipping most of the error messages because there are a lot of them:

```
gui_dwrite.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
blowfish.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
crypt.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
sha256.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
undo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
blowfish.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memcpy referenced in function bf_e_cblock
winclip.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
screen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
sha256.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
gui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
gui_w32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
tag.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
term.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
ui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
undo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
screen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
search.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
spell.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
syntax.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
os_mswin.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
os_win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
quickfix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
regexp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
misc2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
normal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
ops.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
option.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
memline.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
menu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
message.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
misc1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
getchar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
hashtab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
mark.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
...
misc2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fwrite
spell.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fwrite
edit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol isalnum referenced in function ins_ctrl_ey
regexp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol isalnum
ui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strncpy
gui_w32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strncpy
libXpm.lib(parse.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strncpy
libXpm.lib(data.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strncpy
regexp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strncpy
screen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strncpy
...
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol close
memfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol close
libXpm.lib(parse.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
libXpm.lib(hashtab.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
libXpm.lib(data.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
libXpm.lib(misc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
...
eval.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
misc2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
os_win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
gui_w32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
libcmt.lib(new_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
libXpm.lib(simx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
eval.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
misc2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
os_win32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
gui_w32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
normal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
regexp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
libXpm.lib(simx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
eval.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
memline.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
misc1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
misc2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol realloc
...
ex_docmd.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol stricmp
ops.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
option.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
search.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
spell.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
fold.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
getchar.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
mark.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
eval.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
ex_cmds.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
ex_docmd.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
ex_getln.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf
window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
gui.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
gui_w32.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
version.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
spell.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
syntax.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
tag.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
term.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
regexp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
screen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
search.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
sha256.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
ops.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
option.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
...
_crt_atexit referenced in function _onexit
libcmt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crt_at_quick_exit referenced in function at_quick_exit
libcmt.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cexit referenced in function __scrt_dllmain_uninitialize_c
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cexit
libcmt.lib(new_scalar.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _callnewh referenced in function "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2@YAPEAX_K@Z)
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _seh_filter_exe referenced in function "int `int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)'::`1'::filt$0" (?filt$0@?0??__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ@4HA)
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _set_app_type referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __setusermatherr referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _configure_narrow_argv referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _get_narrow_winmain_command_line referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
libcmt.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initterm referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)
...
libXpm.lib(rgb.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strdup referenced in function xpmGetRGBfromName
oldnames.lib(strdup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strdup
oldnames.lib(strdup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _strdup
gvim.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 183 unresolved externals
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious. What changed between VS 2013 and VS 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this had already been reported on [vim_dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/YmhhsZKPHNY/hey_S-qBvSgJ), and is due to the re-organization of the C runtime.

Specifically, the `/nodefaultlib` option for the linker seems to cause the problem.

The [patch included in Paul Moore's follow-up](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/YmhhsZKPHNY/wlOGga8mjdcJ) worked for me.

The pre-compiled XPM library included with Vim seems to statically link to MSVCRT. This issue is mentioned in [CRT Library Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx):

> If you have more than one DLL or EXE, then you may have more than one CRT, whether or not you are using different versions of Visual C++. For example, statically linking the CRT into multiple DLLs can present the same problem. Developers encountering this problem with static CRTs have been instructed to compile with `/MD` to use the CRT DLL. Now that the CRT DLL has been renamed to `msvcr110.dll`, applications may have some components linked to `msvcrt.dll` and others to `msvcr110.dll`. If your DLLs pass CRT resources across the `msvcrt.dll` and `msvcr110.dll` boundary, you will encounter issues with mismatched CRTs and need to recompile your project with Visual C++.

I haven't tried to re-compile the included XPM library with VS2015, so XPM support is disabled in my GVim for now.