# memcmp linker error Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors, memcmp

I have a visual studio 2012 c++ project.
I recently uninstalled it and installed visual studio 2015 and upgraded the project.
When i am building the project, getting error as shown below:

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _memcmp referenced in function

Moreover i have not used anywhere in my code memcmp fucntion.

I used the linker verbose function and could see below in output file:

> Found _memcmp
>
> Referenced in MyC++Project.obj
>
> Referenced in libcpmtd.lib(xstrcoll.obj)
>
> Loaded libvcruntimed.lib(__memcmp_.obj)

Two questions here

1.even though i have not used memcmp in my code why i am getting that linker error?

2.why is memcmp being loaded as __memcmp_.obj

I have the following settings also in my project:

1.C++-->Code generation-->Runtime Library is set to /MTd

2.Linker-->Ignore All default libraries is set to nothing

I have tried all the project settings but everything in vain.

I have issue only with this memcmp function which i have not used.

I have used mamcpy and memset and do not have issue with those

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I not able to build Vim with Visual Studio 2015 RC command line tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986585/why-am-i-not-able-to-build-vim-with-visual-studio-2015-rc-command-line-tools)

Comment: i am having issue only with memcmp function which i have not used. I have used memcpy and memset in my code and those do not have any issues.

Comment: The verbose output says xstrcoll.obj referenecs _memcmp, so there's probably the answer to your first question.

Comment: what third party libraries are you using? Looks like an extern C / name mangling issue.

Comment: No use of 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Explicitly add vcruntime.lib or other appropriate version of [CRT Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) to linker parameters (additional dependencies).

When you use memcmp explicitly it is probably handled as [intrinsic function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) and is compiled as inline function.

Comment: Explicitly linking to vcruntime.lib fixed this issue for me. I am porting a C++ application from VS2005 to VS2015 and ran across this error when compiling IDL proxies. The generated code uses IID_GENERIC_CHECK_IID macro which uses memcmp.

Comment: I added vcruntime.lib, ucrt.lib, made sure I was /MD and changed the call to msvcrtd.lib over to msvcrt.lib for libpng (older version and libz 1.2.5) to build properly from the included project files on windows.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add `vcruntime.lib` and `ucrt.lib` to your additional dependencies. **===> properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies**

Sample path of `'vcruntime.lib': "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\vcruntime.lib"`

Sample path of `'ucrt.lib' : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\x86\ucrt.lib"`

My environment: **VS2017 (v141)**

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same problem with a legacy Visual C++ 6.0 `nmake` file with Visual Studio 2015.

This blog article, [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/), describes how the Visual Studio 2015 runtime has been split into more than one library. The runtime is now "split the CRT into two logical parts: The VCRuntime, which contained the compiler support functionality required for things like process startup and exception handling, and a “stable” part that contained all of the purely library parts of the CRT" to allow for easier updates.

> So long as you do not link with the `/nodefaultlib` option, all of the
> correct library files will be found when you link your project. If you
> link with the `/nodefaultlib` option, you will need to link several
> extra libraries when you link. For example, whereas you previously
> might have just linked `msvcrt.lib` in order to use the CRT DLL, you
> will now also need to link `vcruntime.lib` and `ucrt.lib`. Here is a table
> that shows which libraries you will need to link for each “flavor” of
> the libraries:
>
> ```
> Release DLLs   (/MD ): msvcrt.lib   vcruntime.lib      ucrt.lib
> Debug DLLs     (/MDd): msvcrtd.lib  vcruntimed.lib     ucrtd.lib
> Release Static (/MT ): libcmt.lib   libvcruntime.lib   libucrt.lib
> Debug Static   (/MTd): libcmtd.lib  libvcruntimed.lib  libucrtd.lib
> ```

See also the Microsoft documentation [C runtime (CRT) and C++ Standard Library (STL) .lib files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-160) which describes details about the libraries.

See also [Microsoft C/C++ change history 2003 - 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015?view=msvc-160).