# How to prevent auto optimization from for loop to memset() in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, for-loop, compiler-optimization, memset

I'm developing a program without using CRT , so, some third party using very naive implementation of memset() likes:

```
char x[10];
for(int i= 0; i< 10; i++) {
  x[i] = '\0';
}
```

It's alot of this type of code in that 3rd party library, and, I do not like messing around with it, so, how could I prevent Visual Studio from automatically converting from for loop to memset() ?

Edit: Why this is a problem ?
Since, my program does not use CRT, so, if Visual Studio auto converts the for loop to memset(), it will cause the error:

```
Unresolved external symbol _memset
```

Comment: What do you gain by not dealing with `memset`?

Comment: char x[10] = {0}; will do the trick, too, and you would not need the loop at all.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that will most likely also call memset.

Comment: dasblinkenlight: That's the code inside 3rd party lib, and, I do not want to modify it.

Comment: coderredoc: I'm not using CRT (the CRT is not linked to my program, so, I could not use it)

Comment: @BùiVănThủ.: Compiler optimizes it doesn't mean that it will chance your `.c` files - it's in assembly or machine code. You are aware of that?

Comment: @coderredoc : Common Language Runtime, i.e. Standard C library, e.g. functions in stdio.h

Comment: @coderredoc : see my edit to see why it's a problem.

Comment: perhaps compile with debugging enabled? That should force it to preserve everything right?

Comment: quick question, how do you know that VS is converting the code to `memset`?

Comment: You could probably add /Od (disable optimizations) in your project settings.  But why not just write a simple memset function yourself and link it in?

Comment: @smac89 : see my edit, I'm not using memset(), and get error of "Unresolved external"

Comment: That's kinda hard to give an answer to. Unless you're saying that this loop is all the code you have and VS is some how converting *that* to `_memset`, you will have to provide more evidence that no part of your code is calling off to `memset`. Only then can we focus solely on what you have provided to assist you with an answer. I don't have VS, but I am willing to bet that if I put that code in a VS compiler, it will not call memset

Comment: @smac89: I know to use 'grep' :D

Comment: @Dave : Sure, but have some problems with linkage for now.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29a4236b-f9bc-4558-a87b-6eb5f86989cd/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-strncmp-referenced-in-function-public-int-thiscall?forum=vclanguage

Comment: Also see this other question which may be a duplicate of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285476/memcmp-linker-error-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @Dave : implement a memset() myself, and got this error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8s7ctwz.aspx

Comment: @smac89 : I've been saying, I'm not using CRT

Comment: @smac89 Replacing zero-initialization code with `memset` call is a common technique used by _all_ compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The only relevant compiler option I see in [the list of compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category), besides disabling optimization, is `/kernel`, which produces a binary that can run in the Windows kernel. That is a big hammer; it alters compilation in several ways. Building for the kernel is something one might expect would instruct the compiler not to use library routines. However, [the specific page for that switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/kernel-create-kernel-mode-binary) does not mention it, so I doubt the switch includes that.

Given this, I do not think Visual Studio has a feature of producing stand-alone code that does not use library routines.

Comment: BTW, the GCC equivalent is `-fno-builtin` (or `-ffreestanding` which implies `-fno-builtin`). https://godbolt.org/z/b93oq8boq  Clang will skip the optimization with `-fno-builtin-memset`, but for GCC that just stops `memset(&myvar, 0, 4)` from inlining to a single store instruction, not from inventing calls to standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly remember, MSVC used to have an option for explicitely not use the C run time library. My version was not English,  but it should be something like: *Use standard libraries*. It was used to produce an executable with no dependancies beyond Windows API, which is your current requirement.

---

According to the MSVC page about [NODEFAULTLIB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries), the option still exists on recent versions and should do what you need:

> **If you use /NODEFAULTLIB, for example, to build your program without the C run-time library**, you may have to also use /ENTRY to specify the entry point (function) in your program.

I could not test (no access to a MSVC installation), but I would bet a coin that MSVC will not try to use a function from the CRT when you set this option.

---

IMHO, MSVC should not optimize the loop to a `memset` call, because it defeats a stand alone environment build. Anyway, a possible workaround is to provide à private `memset` version wrapping the WinAPI function `ZeroMemory`.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with /NODEFAULTLIB, the compiler still optimizes to memset()