# Not build after converting project into Visual Studio 2015 ?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-runtime

We have an application which is run and build in visual studio 2010, after converting it into Visual Studio 2015 we are getting following error,

***Error    LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _memcmp referenced in function***

I have looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986585/why-am-i-not-able-to-build-vim-with-visual-studio-2015-rc-command-line-tools) but did not understand properly 
Its seems like something has changed in Visual Studio 2015 compiler and I am missing some settings to overcome this problem.

Could somebody please explain what has changed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285476/memcmp-linker-error-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for quick reply, I had look at the above post and try to link "vcruntime.lib" but still I am getting same error. Could you please suggest or write step how to link this library, may be I have missed some steps or settings.

Comment: Can somebody please help what can be done next to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Thank you Dmitry ! your comment has helped me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

we have used make file to build and generate file, to run successfully nmake command we need to link "vcruntime.lib" library file in Visual Studio 2015 and resolves the issue.
Thank you !!